# How do you open PDF's in app for Sharepoint online

Tags: pdf, adobe, sharepoint-online, acrobat

No option to open in app for PDF's in sharepoint online

when trying to open a pdf document directly from sharepoint online the only option is to open in web.

When we try to open any word or excel files it gives the option to open in app.

How do we enable/configure this option for pdf's as well

Answer (score 1):

For your question, for now, I am afraid that it is not available for opening non-Office files in the application by default.
I have test this problem and found that we can open PDF files in Adobe Acrobat Desk app.

[image]
[image]

Comment: How did you enable this opton?

Comment: I don't have certain special features turned on. Just click on the file after the... then select open->open in Adobe Acrobat. You can click on the blue link in my answer, that is the picture of my operation. Please forgive me for not being very good at uploading pictures yet as I am new to this community.